# How do I tensor differentiate a factor without tensors?

Tags: tensor-calculus, differentiation

How do I tensor differentiate a factor without tensor, such as:

$$\partial_\mu e^{i\Lambda(x)}\tag{1}$$

Should it be zero or should I differentiate it twice changing the order of the tensors follows:

$$\partial_\mu e^{i_\mu \Lambda^\mu}+ \partial_\mu e^{i^\mu \Lambda_\mu}= ({i_\mu + \Lambda_\mu} )e^{i\Lambda }$$

**If the latter case is the correct one, must I keep the tensors in the $i$ and in the $\Lambda$ that were brought down ?**

Comment: Is $u$ a four vector?

Comment: That was a mistake I will correct it now

Comment: Is i the imaginary unit as well?

Comment: Yes it is, hence part of my confusion. Can I just add tensors to it like that? I don't think so but I am uncertain

Comment: No, not really. However, I can see what you are trying to do. What you can do is define a "Identity" four vector $I_\mu=(1,1,1,1)$ and use that to expand out the $\Lambda$ four vector

Comment: But what if the only thing I now about $Lambda(x)$ is that it is a function of $x$? Ican'texpand that. Is it possible to differentiate this without expanding? Or is it just zero?

Comment: Neither $i$ nor $\Lambda$ is a four-vector and there are no tensors here except in the pedantic sense that $\partial_\mu$ is a “tensor with one index”. Do you understand how to differentiate, say, $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}e^{i\Lambda(t,x,y,z)}$? If not, review the “chain rule” for differentiation.

Comment: The $x$ argument in $\Lambda(x)$ is shorthand for $\Lambda(x^\mu)$ or $\Lambda(t,x,y,z)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a standard application of the chain rule.  If $\Lambda$ is a scalar function of $\mathbf x = (x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)$, then

$$\partial_\mu e^{i\Lambda (\mathbf x)}  = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} e^{i\Lambda(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)} = i\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial x^\mu} e^{i\Lambda(\mathbf x)} = i(\partial_\mu\Lambda)e^{i\Lambda(\mathbf x)}$$